# Is it possible to leave a compliment on a Gitlab merge request?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using Gitlab for merge requests at work, and I want leave a compliment on a merge request. Unfortunately, the only related functionality I see in Gitlab are ways to "Start a Review" and "Add comment now", which create threads that are intended to critique the author's code so as to fix issues before merging. I'd rather not use the existing mechanism to leave compliments because based on the usual etiquette, a reviewer needs to resolve each thread before the MR is approved and merged.

Is there some functionality in Gitlab that can enable me to give positive feedback in addition to negative feedback where appropriate?

[image: Gitlab comment functionality]

Comment: I think that's a comment. Whether or not it's an acceptable way to compliment something is more of a culture question in your company than a software development question.

Comment: I would agree if it wasn't for the fact that comments start threads that are in an "unresolved" state on Gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/discussions/):

> Two types of comments are available:
>
> - A standard comment.
> - A comment in a thread, which can be resolved.

On the `Overview` tab of a merge request it is possible to leave both types. On the `Changes` tab it is possible to leave only `comment in a thread`.